# Is it possible to create non-fullscreen modal on android with react-native core component modal?

Tags: android, react-native

On ios, `Modal` component from core `react-native` library renders only to contain all the content, if the height isn't set explicitly.

On android, unlike ios, modal is rendered fullscreen by default and there seems no workaround, to render it, say, 60% of the screen.

Am I missing something or this styling is just not supported?

Answer (score 0):

there is no style prop for modal.

what you can do is set height and width for `</View>` inside modal

```
<Modal transparent={true}
       visible={true}
       onRequestClose={this.closeModal}>
  <View style={{
          color:'transparent', 
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{
            width: 300,
            height: 300}}>
      ...
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```